# Incomplete space

Tags: functional-analysis

I must show that $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ space of all continuous real functions $f:\mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with compact support is not a complete space endowed by norm
$\|f\|=\sup\limits_{t \in \mathbb{R}}|f(t)|$.

Thank for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: find a sequence whose limit does not have compact support.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You can use [indicator functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Baire's theorem to obtain $n\in \mathbb N$ such that every element of $C_0(\mathbb R)$
would have support in $[-n,n]$.